# Adding a choice to a choice field if it is not there

Tags: django, forms, model, view

Hi I currently have this model

```
class Member(models.Model,get_fields):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length = 20)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length = 20)

ROLE_CHOICES = (
    ('PLAYER', 'Player'),
    ('CONDUCTOR', 'Conductor'), 
    ('COMMITTEEMEMBER', 'Committee Member'),
    ('LIBRARIAN', 'Librarian'),
    ('TUTOR', 'Tutor'),
    ('ACCOUNTANT', 'Accountant'),
    ('PRESIDENT', 'President'),
    ('CHAIRMAN', 'Chairman'),
    ('SECRETARY', 'Secretary'),
    ('OTHER', 'Other')
)
role_choices = models.CharField(_('Role'), max_length = 20, choices = ROLE_CHOICES)
```

I would like a user to be able to add an extra role choice if it is not available. So I have also created

```
class ExtraRole(models.Model,get_fields):
    name = models.CharField(max_length = 20)
```

How would I set up the form so that a user is able to create an extrarole on the create member view if it does not exist and then add it into the role_choices tuple? Is it possible to add foreignkeys to the role_choices tuple? Would that be the correct way to do so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be possible to add something similar to a foreign key to role_choices, but this would be very convoluted to create and would also be the 'wrong' way to do it.  You should create a new model for role choices.  Using tuples as your choices is fine if the choices won't change, but if you want to give users the ability to edit these choices then you need to create it as a model and add a foreign key field to the member model

```
class MemberRole(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20)

class Member(models.Model, get_fields):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length = 20)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length = 20)
    role_choices = models.ForeignKey(MemberRole)
```

Comment: I think what he wants is that when 'other' is selected, a text-box with 'please complete' will appear (or already be there but only complete it if 'other' is selected.).

Comment: Even in that case the new model and foreign key is still needed as creating a 'flexible' tuple for the choices is really bad. Situations like this are what foreign keys are for.

Comment: yes, I agree with you. But `ROLE_CHOICES` needs to be kept.

Comment: That isn't mentioned in the question

Comment: Thanks for the answer, sorry I can't upvote it as I don't have enough rep but I should be able to get by with that.